How can I run a function when opening Blender that requires context?
My initial attempt was to call that function directly from the register part. However, I soon realized that this isn't possible for a function that needs context.
I also tried using a load_post handler, but it appears not to fire with a new Blender session, it only triggers when a new file is loaded into an already open Blender.
My latest attempt involved using a timer to call the function. Unfortunately, even though it was successfully registered, the function was never called.
Does anyone have an idea why the timer isn't calling the function, or what else I could try?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/320853/automatic-actions-after-starting-addon/

Add a Cube when registering Add-on
Worked:

Normal blender startup
Reload event
Re/enable add-on

Failed

Indirectly open blender

For directly open a blend file to start the blender, please use
bpy.app.handlers.version_update.append(..)

def register():
    # register_class(...)

    bpy.app.timers.register(test_fn)

def test_fn(): # make sure your start up file have a 3D viewport
    area = next(a for a in bpy.context.screen.areas if a.type == "VIEW_3D")
    region = next(r for r in area.regions if r.type == "WINDOW")

    with bpy.context.temp_override(area=area, region=region):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
        # or test your ops

Valid for both cases
def register():
    # register_class(...)

    bpy.app.handlers.version_update.append(after_scene_code)
    bpy.app.timers.register(after_scene_code)

def after_scene_code():
    if after_scene_code.is_register is True:
        return

    after_scene_code.is_register = True
    test_fn()
after_scene_code.is_register = False

def unregister():
    after_scene_code.is_register = False

    if after_scene_code in bpy.app.handlers.version_update:
        bpy.app.handlers.version_update.remove(after_scene_code)


def test_fn(): # make sure your start up file have a 3D viewport
    area = next(a for a in bpy.context.screen.areas if a.type == "VIEW_3D")
    region = next(r for r in area.regions if r.type == "WINDOW")

    with bpy.context.temp_override(area=area, region=region):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
        # or test your ops


Does this also work instead of using a timer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/320853/automatic-actions-after-starting-addon/

In my case, I use timer method to run a develop Operator when press a button to reload my add-on, instead of bpy.app.handlers Since bpy.app.handlers doesn`t trigger reload event.

@HarryMcKenzie McKenzie  Yes this also work

@HarryMcKenzie  I tested again and it sometimes doesn't work without bpy.context.override .if your operator check the bpy.context.area, and the value is None.

I could make it work using the recommended version_update handler. I also had to set the function to take two arguments, which I don't really know why or where they came from, but I saw that you also did that in your linked post, @HarryMcKenzie so I guess it has to be like that. Thank you both for helping me out!

version_update run when blender start, load_post run when load a blend file. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html

@Tsybe Yeah I think the reason functions like version_update and load_post (among others in Blender's API) require specific parameters, even if they might not use them, is due to a shared interface or function signature requirement imposed by Blender's event handling system.

Thank you for the additional information!
